# google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: File not found when including gRPC using FetchContent_Declare

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I want to use FetchContent to include gRPC in my project.

My proto file looks like:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

package gribserver;

message GetTimeRequest {
  // empty
}

message GetTimeReply {
  google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 1;
}
```

And I build my grpc/proto files using CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(example-grpc LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


message(STATUS "Using gRPC via add_subdirectory (FetchContent).")
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  grpc
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
  GIT_TAG        v1.28.0
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(grpc)

# Since FetchContent uses add_subdirectory under the hood, we can use
# the grpc targets directly from this build.
set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF libprotobuf)
set(_REFLECTION grpc++_reflection)
set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protoc>)
set(_GRPC_GRPCPP grpc++)
if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
  find_program(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE grpc_cpp_plugin)
else()
  set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:grpc_cpp_plugin>)
endif()

# Proto file
get_filename_component(gm_proto "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/grib_manager.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(gm_proto_path "${gm_proto}" PATH)

# Generated sources
set(gm_proto_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gribmanager.pb.cc")
set(gm_proto_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gribmanager.pb.h")
set(gm_grpc_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gribmanager.grpc.pb.cc")
set(gm_grpc_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gribmanager.grpc.pb.h")
add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${gm_proto_srcs}" "${gm_proto_hdrs}" "${gm_grpc_srcs}" "${gm_grpc_hdrs}"
      COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
      ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        --cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        -I "${gm_proto_path}"
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
        "${gm_proto}"
      DEPENDS "${gm_proto}")

add_library(gm_grpc_proto
  ${gm_grpc_srcs}
  ${gm_grpc_hdrs}
  ${gm_proto_srcs}
  ${gm_proto_hdrs})

target_link_libraries(gm_grpc_proto
  ${_REFLECTION}
  ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
  ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF})

# Include generated *.pb.h files
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

This results in the errors:

```
[build] google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: File not found.
[build] grib_manager.proto:3:1: Import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto" was not found or had errors.
[build] grib_manager.proto:27:3: "google.protobuf.Timestamp" is not defined.
[build] grib_manager.proto:36:3: "google.protobuf.Timestamp" is not defined
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: I think there should be an -I "${gm_proto_hdrs }" in your protoc commandline (I am not too familiar with makefiles, but the protoc compiler must also be told to look in the "include" folder of the proto package)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Unfortunately that doesnt work. I believe protobuf sets the value of `gm_proto_hdrs` after it has generated the code. The value of `gm_proto_path` is `/home/tom/src/grpc_test/src/GribManager/protos` which the directory where `grib_manager.proto` lives

Comment: This code works fine if I get rid of any of the `timestamp` proto objects(?)

Comment: can you set an extra include path manually? protoc accepts multiple -I (--protopath) arguments (one for each folder to look in)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I managed to fix it by manually adding `--proto_path="/home/tom/src/grpc_test/build/_deps/grpc-src/third_party/protobuf/src` but im not sure how to get that automatically

Comment: At least it shows you the missing path is the problem. Now you need to find something in your environment that kind of points in that direction. Maybe something from your package manager?